# Getting null value from applicationcontext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, struts2, applicationcontext

I am working on struts2 application with spring for back end.
We are using database.properties file and the entries are as follows:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb  
jdbc.username=root  
jdbc.password=rooooot  
jdbc.csvlocation=C:\myCSV
```

I added the following new entry in database.properties

```
enhancePerf.Flag=true
```

In applicationcontext.xml I am fetching the value like this :-

```
<bean id="userLogin" scope="prototype"  
        class="com.hello.something.actions.UserLoginAction">  
        <property name="perfEnhance" value="${enhancePerf.Flag}"/>  
</bean>
```

After declaring a global variable perfEnhance in UserLoginAction, and forming the setters and getters method of the same, I'm still not getting the value.

I followed the following link:-
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/applicationcontext.xml-properties-file.html

Please advise.

Comment: Are you getting an exception with stacktrace?

Comment: Nope.. I'm not getting any exceptions.  I'm just getting the value of perfEnhance as null.

Comment: Have you defined the location of your properties file? Is your properties file at the correct location?

Comment: I have declared it in applicationcontext.xml as follows :         <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties"/>

Comment: Went through the following link but found nothing new :(   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952872/how-to-have-a-class-use-applicationcontext-beans

Comment: consider showing the source for com.hello.something.actions.UserLoginAction

Comment: Now its working for Service and DAO layers, but for Actionclasses its not working.  @DwB:UserLoginAction just jas setters and getters methods and making use of gettermethod to use it. Working fine in Service and DAO layers !!!

Comment: Are you using the Struts 2 Spring plugin?

Comment: @DaveNewton : Yes my back end is Spring.

Comment: I understand, I'm trying to get confirmation that you've deployed the struts 2 spring plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean, put:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:path/to/database.properties"
                              ignore-unresolvable="false"/>
```

This way if the property is not found, it *will* complain. Otherwise it seems that you may have *another* "database.properties" file in your classpath, that simply does not have such a property.

Make sure that "path/to/database.properties" is in your classpath. If `database.properties` itself is your class path, then no "path/to" is needed => just `classpath:database.properties`

You also have to configure Spring to manage your Actions as beans, using the `ContextLoaderPlugin`, as well as you have to use bean names in Struts config. If you have the following in your `struts-config.xml` file:

```
<action path="/users" .../>
```

You must define that Action's bean with the "/users" name in `action-servlet.xml`:

```
<bean name="/users" .../>
```

Please take a look at [Spring Struts Integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/web-integration.html#struts) from official Spring's docs.

#### EDIT to answer the comment:

`context` is an XML namespace that should be defined in the XML file where it is used:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error in applicationcontext.xml : The prefix "context" for element "context:property-placeholder" is not bound.

Comment: you have to add the namespace definition. I updated the answer with the example

Comment: Still no joy :(. Value can be fetched in service and DAO but not in action. Also I'm getting an exception when I use   ignore-unresolvable="false"

Comment: post the exception to your question. also make sure you are using a bean name in your `struts.xml` rather than a full class name.

Comment: also make sure you look at Spring documentation link I added, and use `ContextLoaderPlugin` plugin.